# Saved user/password null on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get username/password saved value(I saved the user/pass on my browser) when a page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    validate();
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        validate();
    });

    function validate(){
      console.info($("#username").val())
       console.info($("#password").val())

    }
```

but it keeps coming empty. When I start typing then only it outputs value.

Comment: Try `window.onload = function(){...}`

Comment: How do you save it? In your code you only output elements values (on page load it's empty). Also DON'T save sensitive information in browser (user accessible area) - security issue, use server side

Comment: @^^ The client saves the user/pass not me.

Comment: my thought is that it is not safe to load the password on onload

Comment: which html element `username` and `password` are? hidden fields?

Comment: @OAD Visible text fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your function before calling it.

Try this code:

```
function validate(){
  console.info($("#username").val())
  console.info($("#password").val())
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").keyup(function(){
        validate();
    });

    validate();
  });
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/qd9cr5xd/

Comment: For that code to work, your #username and #password input must have a value attribute set. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/qd9cr5xd/

Comment: but the saved content is managed by the browser. How can I set the value attribute.

Comment: If it's previously typed by the user, that value could be saved in localStorage or a cookie. Declaring the function before calling it, in this case, wouldn't make a difference due to hoisting. If the function was declared as `var valudate = function() {}` then the order of calling would make a difference. More on localStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

> above code works perfectly.
>   But if you are storing value in hidden fields then you should assign value of >each hidden fields to respective HTML element.

```
function validate(){
  console.info($("#username").val())
  console.info($("#password").val())
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").val($("hdnUserName").val());
    $("#password").val($("hdnPassword").val());
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        validate();
    });

    validate();
});
```